# HTML FORM CLIENT VALIDATION

Tags: javascript, html, validation, client

I'm quite new to the javascript scene not to mention working with it on a rails application. So i decided to do a client side validation of my signup form everything works ok but my script for checking if password matches confirm password. Everytime it tells me password does not match i was really hoping someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance :)   P.S this is mostly html and javascript

```
     <head>
    <form id="sign_up" method="post" action="/auth/identity/register">   
      <div class="field"> 
        <input id="name" class="username" type="text" placeholder="Full name" name="name" required></input>
     </div>
     <div class="field"> 
        <input id="email" class="username" type="email" placeholder="Email address" name="email" required></input>
     </div>
     <div class="field"> 
        <input id="password" class="username" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required></input>
    </div>
    <div class="field"> 
    <input id="password_confirmation" class="username" type="password" placeholder="Password confirmation" name="password_confirmation" required></input>
    </div>

      <div class="field"> 
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign up" name="commit"></input>
      </div>

     </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("password").onchange = validatePassword;
    document.getElementById("password_confirmation").onchange = validatePassword;

}
function validatePassword(){
var pass2=document.getElementById("password_confirmation").value;
var pass1=document.getElementById("password").value;
if(pass1!=pass2){
    document.getElementById("password_confirmation").setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");

}
else
    document.getElementById("password_confirmation").setCustomValidity(''); 
//empty string means no validation error
}

</script>
  </div>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you show your full html and js code.?

Comment: that's my whole js code i did everything in the html

Comment: move your form and script to body. worked fine for me. (tested on firefox24 and chrome33)

Comment: Close `validatePassword()` function ;) And of course put the script just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: It works fine for me, what's the problem?

Comment: I changed it to body it still didn't work for some reason this is a page in a rails app by the way I decided to make this page purely html that's why you can't see any rails on it and also there are two forms on the same page I am quite puzzled by why this isn't working for me

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters have said, your code works when you move it into the `<body>` of the document. Perhaps there's more than one element with ID `password` or `password_confirmation` within the document?

If not I would start by logging the entered password and password_confirmation values, i.e.:

```
console.log("Password box value: "+pass1);
console.log("Password confirmation box value: "+pass2);
```

Put these lines below the line `var pass1=document.getElementById("password").value;`

Then you can visually inspect the entered values in your browser console (`F12` key) to make sure they're the same. Check the values just after you click the submit button. Bear in mind you're binding the `onchange` event to the inputs so you'll see logging when you move from the password input to the password confirmation input (you can ignore this as you won't yet have entered the confirmation password).

Finally, it's worth bearing in mind that Firefox behaves slightly differently to Chrome in terms of user feedback; Firefox puts a red glow around the offending text input as you type, which disappears when the password entered in the password confirmation input is the same. Chrome does not do this and only gives indication that the passwords didn't match after you click the submit button.